# hook to change image styles before rendering nodes

Tags: panels, media

I need to change the image style (or effects of the style) saved in the field display option from page manager when the page rendered to the user based on other fields values in the same node.

HOOK_NODE_VIEW() gives the style saved with the field from the field display option not the one that I created by panels.

I wonder how panels override that value for the style and HOOK_NODE_VIEW() didn't catch it.

so which hook should i look for.It may be related to panels module ,but really I need help because it took so much time and I reach to nothing.

Comment: Page manager (optionally) sidesteps the entire normal rendering flow, which is why you see different things on node view compared to page manager rendering. What I don't understand about your question is how node_view is relevant. Are you saying that somehow the normal node_view already does what you want?

Comment: I mean node_view should told me about the image style I  assigned from panels and so I could easily change.

Comment: Sorry, this still doesn't make sense to me. Please consider re-phrasing your question, and we'll see if I can help. :)

Comment: any way I fixed the by another solution by duplicating the field and set visibility rules.

Simply I need a hook to change the image style per node view page request